# How to read the keys from array using robot framework?

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I need to read the two keys named value from an array. I am able to read one key. Need a help in reading two keys named 'value'

I have used Robot Framework.

RobotFramework.robot:

```
 ${readvalues}=  [{u'count': 1, u'id': u'vegetable', u'value': u'veg'}, {u'count': 1, u'id': u'Non_vegetarian', u'value': u'Non_veg'}]

 ${read_prv_value}=     Set Variable     ${readvalue['value']}
 log to console   ${read_prv_value}   #prints Non-veg alone I expected Veg and Non Veg
  ${value_cnt}=    Get Length    ${readvalues}
  : FOR    ${item}    IN RANGE   0    ${value_cnt}
         \    ${readvalue}=    Set Variable     ${var[${item}]['value']}
```

I expected Veg and Non Veg, but the actual o/p is Non Veg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that a list of two dictionaries? Then you'll have to loop the list or use the separate dictionaries giving list indices.

```
Read with loop
${d1}=    Create Dictionary    count=1    id=vegetable    value=veg
${d2}=    Create Dictionary    count=1    id=Non_vegetarian    value=Non_veg
${readvalues}=  Create List    ${d1}    ${d2}
: FOR    ${item}    IN    @{readvalues}
\    ${value}=    Set Variable     ${item}[value]
\    Log To Console    ${value}

Read without loop
    ${d1}=    Create Dictionary    count=1    id=vegetable    value=veg
    ${d2}=    Create Dictionary    count=1    id=Non_vegetarian    value=Non_veg
    ${readvalues}=  Create List    ${d1}    ${d2}
    ${value1}=    Set Variable     ${readvalues}[0][value]
    Log To Console    ${value1}
    ${value2}=    Set Variable     ${readvalues}[1][value]
    Log To Console    ${value2}
```

Both keywords log:

```
veg
Non_veg
```

Comment: Can you help me with code that I have tried using for loop?